# Bash script that searches for directories with files called package.json and install dependencies

Tags: beginner, array, bash

I'm relatively familiar with the command line, but I've usually reached for other languages rather than bash for more full on scripts. It works, but I'm wondering if anything isn't really idiomatic. I've never used bash arrays before, and I've never had to write such an involved find command so I'm just wondering if I did all that fine. Also just overall is there a shorter way to do this?

.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# The directories to search in
# Currently, lib + tools, and whatever command line args are provided
DIRS=(lib tools $@)
for i in "${!DIRS[@]}";
do
  DIRS[i]="$(pwd)/${DIRS[i]}"
done

# Get absolute path of directories with a package.json file and install dependencies
while IFS='' read -r line; do
  echo "Installing dependencies for $line"
  cd "$line" && yarn
done < <(
  find "${DIRS[@]}" -iname 'package.json' -not -path '*/node_modules/*' -exec dirname {} \;
)

# Do current directory
echo "Installing dependencies for current directory"
yarn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Working with `$@`

If some command line arguments contain spaces this won't work:

> ```
> DIRS=(lib tools $@)
> ```

In 99% of use cases you probably want to double quote `$@`.

#### Unnecessary work

It's unnecessary to execute `$(pwd)` in a loop if the directory doesn't change in between cycles:

> ```
>   DIRS[i]="$(pwd)/${DIRS[i]}"
> ```

A simple fix is using `$PWD` instead, which will not incur command execution:

```
  DIRS[i]="$PWD/${DIRS[i]}"
```

#### Building arrays

This is not very idiomatic:

> ```
> DIRS=(lib tools $@)
> for i in "${!DIRS[@]}";
> do
>   DIRS[i]="$(pwd)/${DIRS[i]}"
> done
> ```

It would be better like this:

```
DIRS=()
for i in lib tools "$@"
do
  DIRS+=("$PWD/$i")
done
```

#### `cd` in a sub-shell

This works because you made sure the paths are absolute paths:

> ```
> while IFS='' read -r line; do
>   echo "Installing dependencies for $line"
>   cd "$line" && yarn
> done < <(
>   find "${DIRS[@]}" -iname 'package.json' -not -path '*/node_modules/*' -exec dirname {} \;
> )
> ```

If the paths had been relative, this wouldn't work.
That's why you built `DIRS`, a considerable extra effort.
There's a way to make this safe even with relative paths,
by wrapping `cd && yarn` in a sub-shell:

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do
  echo "Installing dependencies for $line"
  (cd "$line" && yarn)
done < <(
  find lib tools "$@" -iname 'package.json' -not -path '*/node_modules/*' -exec dirname {} \;
)
```

Without `DIRS`, the script can be shorter and simpler.

#### `find ... -execdir`

If your version of `find` supports the `-execdir` option,
and if you don't mind not printing the "Installing dependencies for ...",
then you can further simplify the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Install dependencies in directories with a package.json file
find lib tools "$@" -iname 'package.json' -not -path '*/node_modules/*' \
  -execdir yarn \;

# Do current directory
echo "Installing dependencies for current directory"
yarn
```

If you really *do* want to print that informational line,
that's possible, though not very sexy:

```
find lib tools "$@" -iname 'package.json' -not -path '*/node_modules/*' \
  -exec printf Installing dependencies for \; -execdir pwd \; -execdir yarn \;
```